# rails Multiple selector from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I would like to create a multiple selection field, the values are stored in an array and not in a database, I managed to select several values and they are saved in a database but they are saved as a string instead of an array.

How can I retrieve them when I edit my profile?

```
@spoken_languages_datas = [["Allemand", 0], ["Anglais", 1], ["Anglais ( Australien )", 2], ["Anglais ( Royaume Uni )", 3], ["Arabe", 4], ["Chinois", 5], ["Espagnol", 6], ["Espagnol ( Chili )", 7], ["Danois", 8], ["Finlandais", 9], ["Français", 10], ["Français ( Canada )", 11], ["Grec  ", 12], ["Italien", 13], ["Japonais", 14], ["Portugais", 15], ["Portugais ( Brésil )", 16], ["Néerlandais", 17], ["Norvégien", 18], ["Russe", 19], ["Suédois", 20], ["Turc", 21]]
```

my form :

```
.row
  .col-6
    = form.label :spoken_languages, @spoken_languages_title
    = form.select(:spoken_languages, @spoken_languages_datas.each { |p| [p] }, {prompt: 'Select a language'}, {multiple: true, size: @spoken_languages_datas.count, style: 'height: 125px;'})
```

values once stored in the database:

```
"[\"\", \"0\", \"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]"
```

Comment: You can serialize the :spoken_languages field in your model i.e.
`class ModelName < ApplicationRecord; serialize :spoken_languages, Array; ... end`.

Comment: All right, that works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` method to turn your string into array (but be very careful with that method... you shouldn't use it for manipulating data coming from user - code injection danger).
But I would suggest, as Jean already pointed out, to use serialize on your model, like this:

```
serialize :spoken_languages
```

That way, active record handles it for you, saving as a String, and giving you back an array when you access the attribute. Good luck!